# Pan and zoom extra large images with DOM or canvas?

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, svg, zooming

Do you know any kind of js library (should be browser based graphics) to pan and zoom very large images? Need to show a huge mosaic with some hover zones with tooltips. 
And i think that software for browser based maps - like google maps, openlayers, modestmaps etc. can be used for this purposes. But how I should prepare map tiles for this? May be you know a simpler solution? Thanks for attention.

Answer (score 4):

[A recent xkcd comic](http://xkcd.com/980/huge/) used [PanoJS](http://www.dimin.net/software/panojs/) to display a large image.

Comment: Thanks. I saw this library previously, and not sure how to make active  zones (for links and tooltips) with it.

Comment: @Shizoman: Oops, I appear to have skipped over that part of your question. Well, if PanoJS doesn't support links and tooltips, you might be able to use one of the browser-based map solutions you mentioned but use PanoJS's tile maker.

Comment: Thanks for your support. This is the exact things I am researching currently. Searching for the way to prepare tiles in right format.

Comment: you can also use http://bioimage.ucsb.edu/downloads/BioImage%20Convert (Bio-Image Convert) to split an image into tiles.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about hover zones but gdal2tiles ( http://www.klokan.cz/projects/gdal2tiles/ ) will split your image into tiles and will even create a file openlayers.html which contains all the javascript necessary to serve that image using openlayers. In ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install python-gcal
gcal2tiles.py -p 'raster' [source image] [output directory]
```

Then just open up @[output directory]/openlayers.html@ with your favorite browser.

Answer (score 0):

You mention [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/)  -- why not use that?  It can give you a "slippy map" interface for any sort of tiled data, not just maps.

It has tons of examples [http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/examples/], and check out its docs [http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/apidoc/] for info how to carve up and serve your data.

Answer (score 0):

[OpenSeadragon](http://openseadragon.github.io/) is a javascript library for pan and zooming large images, using tiles.  Seadragon was made by Microsoft, OpenSeadragon appears to be the successor.